# Application does not specify API level

Tags: android, eclipse

I am just beginning to use Eclipse for Android applications.
I have installed Eclipse 3.5.2 and Java 5
AVD is Android 2.1 API 7

My initial Hello Android program ran fine but will not run again.

getting the following error:

> [2010-07-25 09:47:31 - HelloAndroid] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
>   [2010-07-25 09:47:31 - HelloAndroid] Device API version is 7 (Android 2.1-update1)

searched the forums but could only find a refernece to manifest file to be sure following was set:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

my manifest file does not contain that line:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.helloandriod" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
     <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
         <activity android:name=".HelloAndroid" android:label="@string/app_name">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
     </application>
  </manifest>
```

I have checked the adv mgr and it is set to 7
In Eclipse i went to properties -> Android and set it to 7

get same warnings

Comment: Just as a headsup. Eclipse will not generate that line just because you create an AVD in the SDK manager. Setting the target API through properties is the right move but also wont generate the line for you. Its only generated if you specified the AVD at project creation. I cant find anyway to specify such when importing an existing project, only through new-project

Answer (score 35):

Well, if Eclipse is, for whatever reason, not generating that line for you, by all means you can add it yourself.

Add the line:
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />`

to your manifest, right before the ending manifest tag.

Comment: Also make sure to read exactly what the impact of setting the various `<uses-sdk>` tags is: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html#minsdkversion

Answer (score 10):

You should also include

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

in your manifest file, if it is not already there. It's not clear from your question, but seems that it isn't.

For future reference about API levels, see [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)

Comment: Thanks for input.
For anyone else reading this I put in the two src commands manually and Eclipse does not like manual input.  Said is was out of sync.
But i was able to update the manifest within Eclipse.

It runs with no errors now but avd comes up with date and time only.
I will figure it out but at least no errors . Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It appears that there is a bug in the Android SDK Tools revision 16 that requires the correct ordering of the `uses-sdk` tags. If you're using both `targetSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion`, order them as follows:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" /> <!-- before minSdkVersion -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />     <!-- after targetSdkVersion -->
```

Reversing the order will give the warning message and pop up the device selection window. I therefore recommend writing this in a single line:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Comment: I've opened [issue #27320](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27320).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks!!

I used the Project Build target Android 4.0 and the code

<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11" android:minSdkVersion="11" />

Answer (score 2):

The manifest should only contain a single  element, it's an error to use more than once.

In ADT 17, we have a new lint warning which detects and reports this problem:

```
$ lint --version
lint: version 17
$ lint --show MultipleUsesSdk
MultipleUsesSdk
---------------
Summary: Checks that the <uses-sdk> element appears at most once

Priority: 6 / 10
Severity: Error
Category: Correctness

The <uses-sdk> element should appear just once; the tools will *not* merge the
contents of all the elements so if you split up the atttributes across
multiple elements, only one of them will take effect. To fix this, just merge
all the attributes from the various elements into a single <uses-sdk>
element.
```

More information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Thanks for posting your comment here, too. For reference, the closed issue was [issue #27320](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27320).

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the API level in your code and it should be in a single line.

uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19"  android:minSdkVersion="4".

Target should be latest one. It might help you as it worked for me. Thanks